# Accessibility: camera switches and project activate: when will these be available internationally?

Tags: camera, accessibility, front-camera

I have a friend with amyotrophic lateral sclerosis. As a result of this, muscles do not receive nourishment in a progressively worsening manner, so that the muscles start becoming more and more impaired and unable to move with time.

I have been exploring camera switches and project activate on Android, hoping that it would allow my friend to communicate through their phone and operate their phone in the later stages of their disabling condition.

These features are described here:
[Disabled people can now use Android phones with face gestures](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2021/09/24/business/google-android-disabilities/)

With them, you can raise your eyebrows, look left, up, or right, or smile or open your mouth to perform various actions such as play a prerecorded sound, make a phone call, or call a carer, and with project activate you can also use these camera switches to navigate your phone.

However, I learned that these are only available in Australia, Britain, Canada and the United States.

I don't understand why such a useful feature would be geographically restricted. I am living abroad and cannot find activate on Google Play, although I need it. Does anyone know when these will be available intentionally, or whether there is anything I can use in the meantime?

Comment: Based on [Meet the 13 newest Android features.](https://www.android.com/google-features-on-android/fall-2021/#fall-2021-accessibility-header), "*Camera Switches will be made widely available on September 30th.*" which links to the [Android Accessibility Suite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.marvin.talkback) app.

Comment: For [Project Activate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.vision.switches), we can't really say anything because we're not Google nor affiliated with Google.